# How long does official Lego monorail track last?

Tags: durability, monorail

Given the high cost of official Lego monorail track, I was wondering how long it tends to last/if there are any maintenance tips or tricks? I'm planning on using power functions to reduce the start/stop strain, but is there anything else to increase longevity?

Answer (score 3):

Try to keep the track in mint condition. For example, don't expose it to extreme heat or cold. Keep it away from any pets or children who don't know better. Looking at some pictures, it seems that the vehicle on the monorail runs on a gear. Try interchanging gears every so often so that the gears don't wear and the teeth don't get bent or break.

Comment: One of my concerns is that since the gear is metal it may wear away the teeth on the track. Is there an oil (perhaps vegetable?) that won't attack the plastic?

Comment: Yes, vegetable oil would make a good lubricant as it does not wear away plastics or rubbers when applied.

Answer (score 2):

The track is pretty durable.  I have several pieces of old track that the motor runs on well.
With the 3D printers now available I am hoping to be able to "print" some of the track with ABS filament.  Getting the gear teeth just right will be the tricky part and the end connectors.

Comment: The track seems to last quite a while.  There are people in my LUG who have been using the same track for over a decade of pretty routine displays.  Those same guys are currently working on using 3D printing to create something to build a mold on.  It seems to be working pretty well for them, so far.

Comment: I am hoping to use something like Autodesk to make a prototype, then get the files into STL format and send it to a 3D printer.  The 'teeth cogs" are just a few millimeters between each one.  I am sure there will be many renditions before I get it right.  It would be great to be able to make a cross track, but that could be a challenge right in the center of the X.  I will start with straight and curves first.